# ufw not blocking (cloudflare)

Tags: cloudflare, ufw

My site is behind cloudflare and i seem to be having a problem with ufw firewall.

setup:

apache, mod_remoteip (all access logs) for apache are showing correct IP

UFW:

Deny all incoming, Allow all outgoing & SSH port is open.

Ive used a script to only allow cloudflares IP range to my server on port 80 and 443 [Cloudflare Script](https://designinterventionsystems.com/plone-blog/configuring-the-ufw-firewall-to-allow-cloudflare-ip-addresses)

The problem is if i ban from example: sudo ufw deny from 95.167.1.5 to any

Why can i still visit my site from that IP?

The correct IP is being logged in apache.
Its banned if i try to connect to ssh.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Cloudflare then you can't ban any IP by UFW because all connections will be made by Cloudflare internal IP, not the client IP. But, If you are doing by using apache `.httacces` file, Then it's possible to do.

Install `mode_cloudflare`: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170916-Restoring-original-visitor-IPs-Option-1-Installing-mod-cloudflare

To block IP: add code below in your `.htaccess` file.

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Note: replace `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with your desired IP to block.